# Does the Terralith mod work for Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-mods

Does the [Terralith](https://www.planetminecraft.com/data-pack/terralith-overworld-evolved-100-biomes-caves-and-more/) mod work for Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with behavior packs, but right now no one made a Bedrock version.